Unable to convert JSONArray to List<Map<String, String>>
As the title suggests, I am trying to convert JSONArray to List<Map<String, String>>. Here is the code:
String json = """
                {
                    "users": [
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                            "name": "John Doe",
                            "email": "john.doe@example.com"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "2",
                            "name": "Jane Smith",
                            "email": "jane.smith@example.com"
                        }
                    ],
                    "docs": {
                        "PAN": {
                            "id": "a1234567-b89b-12d3-a456-426614174000",
                            "type": "PAN",
                            "metadata": "121312"
                        },
                        "VOTERID": {
                            "id": "d70711a1-092c-4956-873d-cda5f189f240",
                            "type": "Voter ID",
                            "metadata": "1212121"
                        }
                    },
                    "age": 10
                }
                """;

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("users");

        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Map<String, String>>>() {}.getType();
        List<Map<String, String>> maps = modelMapper.map(jsonArray, listType);
        System.out.println(maps);

The error is as follows:
2024-06-27T14:36:14.041+05:30 ERROR 33039 --- [demo] [nio-8081-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.modelmapper.MappingException: ModelMapper mapping errors:

1) Failed to instantiate instance of destination java.util.List. Ensure that java.util.List has a non-private no-argument constructor.

1 error] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.List.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3585) ~[na:na]


Use: modelMapper.map(jsonArray.toList(), listType);

@nguyenhuyenag its working. Thanks
